# Cannot import Snapkit into KeyboardViewController

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, snapkit

I cant import SnapKit to KeyboardViewController (UIInputViewController) class, it says no such module SnapKit.

Answer (score 0):

First you can clean your project,close it and open again,if it does not work,It tell you that you did not install it in right way,see more in http://snapkit.io/docs/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the framework to embedded libraries.

1. In your workspace select the first option (blue page symbol with the Xcode project name)
2. In the General section, you will see Embedded Libraries.
3. Drag and drop the SnapKit.framework file.
4. The framework should be in the Xcode project folder. For e.g if you are using Carthage it will be in Xcode Project Folder -> Carthage -> Build -> iOS -> SnapKit.framework